# Incorrect deserialization of SOAP message in .NET app

Tags: c#, .net-core, soap, deserialization, .net-6.0

I am working on converting an existing application from .NET Framework to .NET 6. Deserialization of SOAP message no longer works as expected.

I have the following response message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:findAgreementResponse
         xmlns:ns2="example.webservices.licensing.secure"
         xmlns:ns3="example.webservices.exceptions">
         <return>
            <description>Standard</description>
            <idLicenseAgreement>1234</idLicenseAgreement>
         </return>
      </ns2:findAgreementResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

With the .NET Framework, the code generated when I added a service reference included this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(agreement))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3221.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://example.org/licensing/")]
public partial class messageBase {     
     private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;     
     private string messageIdField;
     
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
     public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
         get { return this.anyField; }
         set { this.anyField = value; }
     }
     
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
     public string messageId {
         get { return this.messageIdField; }
         set { this.messageIdField = value; }
     }
}
 
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3221.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://example.org/licensing/")]
public partial class agreement : messageBase {
     
     private string descriptionField;     
     private long idLicenseAgreementField;     
     private bool idLicenseAgreementFieldSpecified;
     
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
     public string description {
         get { return this.descriptionField; }
         set { this.descriptionField = value; }
     }
     
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
     public long idLicenseAgreement {
         get { return this.idLicenseAgreementField; }
         set { this.idLicenseAgreementField = value; }
     }
     
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
     public bool idLicenseAgreementSpecified {
         get { return this.idLicenseAgreementFieldSpecified; }
         set { this.idLicenseAgreementFieldSpecified = value; }
     }
}

[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace="example.webservices.licensing.secure", ResponseNamespace="example.webservices.licensing.secure", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public agreement findAgreement([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] string arg0) {
   object[] results = this.Invoke("findAgreement", new object[] {
               arg0});
   return ((agreement)(results[0]));
}
```

This worked well, the response was properly deserialized (when calling the `findAgreement` method). When something was not expected (there are many methods and responses), it was added to the `Any` array from `messageBase`.

After migrating to .NET 6, adding the service resulted in the following code:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(agreement))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://example.org/licensing/")]
public partial class messageBase
{
     private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;
     private string messageIdField;
     
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=0)]
     public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any
     {
         get { return this.anyField; }
         set { this.anyField = value; }
     }
     
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
     public string messageId
     {
         get { return this.messageIdField; }
         set { this.messageIdField = value; }
     }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://example.org/licensing/")]
public partial class agreement : messageBase
{
     private string descriptionField;
     private long idLicenseAgreementField;
     private bool idLicenseAgreementFieldSpecified;
     
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
     public string description
     {
         get { return this.descriptionField; }
         set { this.descriptionField = value; }
     }
     
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
     public long idLicenseAgreement
     {
         get { return this.idLicenseAgreementField; }
         set { this.idLicenseAgreementField = value; }
     }
     
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
     public bool idLicenseAgreementSpecified
     {
         get { return this.idLicenseAgreementFieldSpecified; }
         set { this.idLicenseAgreementFieldSpecified = value; }
     }
}


[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="findAgreementResponse", WrapperNamespace="example.webservices.licensing.secure", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class findAgreementResponse
{
     
     [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="example.webservices.licensing.secure", Order=0)]
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
     public agreement @return;
     
     public findAgreementResponse()
     {
     }
     
     public findAgreementResponse(agreement @return)
     {
         this.@return = @return;
     }
}

[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
findAgreementResponse findAgreement(findAgreementRequest request)
{
   return base.Channel.findAgreement(request);
}
```

What happens now is that the `description` and `idLicenseAgreement` properties are not filled in. Instead, the `Any` array from the base class contains both these XML elements:

```
<description>Standard</description>
<idLicenseAgreement>1234</idLicenseAgreement>
```

If I remove the `messageBase` base class, parsing occurs correctly, and the `agreement` object is properly filled in with the data from the SOAP response.

I expect this to be a namespace issue but I was unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem was the explicit ordering of elements. In the code generated by Svcutil in .NET 6, all the XML elements are attributed like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=0)]
```

Once I removed the `Order` property from all of them, deserialization worked as expected.